# Magento 1: Checkout redirecting to empty page

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

Ordering process is redirecting to empty cart in my Magento 1 installation. What I noticed is Magento creates a second "/" Session and Local storage variable and that is probably causing the redirect to empty cart and not success site. Also after log-in in get empty page site.

On all other shop sites there is always just one Session/Local variable.

This is happening on site example.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/.

Does anyone have any advise what is causing this (are there any setting related to that)? 
How could I resoltve this?

[image]

Comment: Please write more about issue. Is  that happened after install any extension, supee or something like that? Please check var/log/system.log and var/log/exceptions. You can also enable enable displaying errors on frontend in index.php for more details

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that you have a permissions problem with your /var folder. This should be writeable by the web server in order to store session information and cached data.

My advice is to first clear the cookies on your browser, try again, then, if no progress, go to the var folder in your Magento root and check that the permissions are set so that the web server can write to it. The exact details of the permissions vary from site to site so you will need to use your linux knowledge there.

Comment: Permission is set to 777 for /var and /var/session folder.